# .htaccess - remove .html and allow at the end of the url with and without trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I would like to use .htaccess to remove the .html extension in the URL and be able to access the URL with or without a trailing slash at the end. Now when I call the page with a slash at the end I get a 500 Internal Server Error

My .htaccess Code:

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Comment: Try adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` before last `RewriteCond`

Comment: I get the same error message

Comment: ok check Apache error..log and see reason of 500 error

Comment: `[core:error] [pid 532904] [client IP] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it like this:

```bash
DirectorySlash Off
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/file.html to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Some Apache implementations can be buggy resolving `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` hence it is better to construct full file path using `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`.